# How to make pagination API in laravel using POST method

Tags: laravel

Suppose i need to fetch user money transactions there are 100+ transactions in database and i need to send all the user transactions through the API to a android app, i have idea how to make using GET method but using GET method its not Dynamic.
In API i'm sorting data by 4-5 parameters in API input using post method
And i want to make this API for infinite Scrolling
And i'm using Stored Procedure for getting data

Then How can i achieve Laravel pagination in POST method?

my current response something like this

```
{
"Transactions"[
{
"name":"food";
"amount":100;
}
]
}
```

Comment: using paginate() or simplePaginate() method would be enough

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do it in multiple ways but the way I use most is like below

```
    public function getTransaction(Request $request)
    {

        $transactions = Transactions::where('SOME-Condition', $request->Condition)->paginate(10);

    $sorted = $transactions ->sortBy([
      ['name', 'asc'],
      ['age', 'desc'],
    ]);
        return $sorted;

    }
```

or you can also do it like this

```
     public function getTransaction(Request $request)
    {

        $transactions = Transactions::where('SOME-Condition', $request->Condition)
->orderBy('abc')
->orderBy('def')
->paginate(10);

        return $sorted;

    }
```